# How do I set the color chosen by user as a background color for the entire IOS App?

Tags: ios, swift

I want the user to choose the preferred color by clicking the wanted button, and based on the choice it will be the background color of all pages in the App.

The code given is what I have used to change the background color through code, as shown in the image attached [Screenshot of page sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ9f1.png)  . However, it changes temporary only and does not get saved when I move to another page and get back.

class ColorViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var redBtn: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var blueBtn: UIButton!


@IBAction func changeToRed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
}
@IBAction func changeToBlue(_ sender: UIButton) {
     self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
}
```

If you also know how to save this color for a registered user (So every time the user signs in, the chosen background stays as is instead of reseting to default) it would be great. Please advise if you know the solution, I am new on Swift.

Answer (score 0):

For saving user's color choice, you can use `UserDefaults`, that will allow you to store small sized information (like color preference) inside memory. So you can use something like this:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(UIColor.red , forKey: "themePreferenceKey")
```

That will store *Red* choice in memory that'll be reachable with key `themePreferenceKey` later on.

For changing view/button background colors according to user's saved choice, you must fetch the value of `themePreferenceKey` whenever a view is **Appeared**, and change the colors accordingly. This can be implemented inside `viewDidAppear` method. Such as:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   if let preferredColor = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "themePreferenceKey") as? UIColor {
      self.view.backgroundColor = preferredColor
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Muhammed, I have kept the first piece of code inside the action button and created the viewDidAppear method with your code.  Once I click the button, my App crashes.  Could not even test if it works, any idea?

Comment: @Noor Well only thing comes to my mind is the UIColor, can you save it as a String instead of UIColor object? Like UserDefaults.standard.set("Red" , forKey: "themePreferenceKey") and then recieve as UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "themePreferenceKey") as? String and print the string to see if it works? Also what error does compiler give, please specify.

Comment: I tried the following:    @IBAction func blueBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
//UserDefaults.standard.set(UIColor.red , forKey: "themePreferenceKey")
UserDefaults.standard.set("Red" , forKey: "themePreferenceKey")
    }

Comment: And this:    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if let preferredColor =
            
            UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "themePreferenceKey") as? String {
            self.view.backgroundColor = preferredColor
            
        //UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "themePreferenceKey") as? UIColor {
            
            
        }
    }

Comment: But I currently get this error on the last line in the viewDidAppear saying: Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'UIColor?'

Comment: As for the first code you provided, I just get this error: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException